# How to set ngModelOptions by javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm creating a custom directive, and this directive will needing handle `ngModelOptions` of element, maybe I can do this changing element html with `jQuery` selector, but I wanted to know if can I do this by `javascript` for better consistency

## UPDATE 1

Because I will need set `ngModelOptions="{updateOn:'blur'}` for all input in my form

So I want create a directive for do this, likely `<input type='text' updateBlur/>`

I wanted to know if is possible set this options with code, likely this

```
myElement.attrs.ngModelOptions.updateOn = "blur default";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it in the "angular way", so you should do something like this in your directive:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('myDirective', function($compile){
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         scope.$watch( 'scope.someValue', function(){
            element.attr('ng-model-options', "new value");
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
         });

    }
});
```

In this way you might check on the change of `scope.someValue`, and apply the new value to the directive. You cannot do this with jquery, because angularJS won't get the changes.

But, using this `$compile(element.contents())(scope);` will do the trick.

**EDIT**: `$scope.apply()`, shouldn't work. Because it's necessary to force a digest cycle (such as more elements are added to an array). Here you're changing the structure, so you need to re-compile it

Comment: $compile(element.contents())(scope);   will get a result similar $scope.$apply() ?

Answer (score 1):

Please be more specific on your problem.

The answer for the general question is that you should not use jQuery selectors for manipulating the DOM if you are using angular.

If what you need is to manipulate the ngModelOptions attribute, you should do that from within your directive, using the arguments of the link function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){ 
   ...
//if you want to change the ngModelOptions attribute
$(element).attr('ng-model-options', 'whatever')
}
```

For a more detailed explanation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive